# Adding element to ScrollView crashes app Android SDK

Tags: android, multithreading, scrollview

I am trying to make an interpreter type thing with my app, where a string from a file on a server is gotten and it is broken down with a split even. Here is the code:

```
public void onBtnClick(View view)
{
    final String message = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText)).getText().toString();
    final String mes = message.replace(".meb", "");
    final TextView urlTextOut = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.URLtextView);
    final ScrollView linearLayout = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.setscroll);
    new Thread() {
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try

            {
                    String str = "";
                    URL url = new URL("http://awsomisoft.com/" + mes + "/" + mes + ".meb");
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

                    while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        text.append(str);
                    }
                    in.close();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e1)

            {
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
            }
            if(message.contains(".meb")) {
                String str[] = text.toString().split("%");
                for (final String l : str) {
                    String code[] = l.split(" ");
                    if (code[0].toString().equals("$")) {
                        //Compile
                    } else {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                final TextView tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                                tv.setText(l);
                                linearLayout.addView(tv);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                if(message == null) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            urlTextOut.setText("404 Error");
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }.start();

}
```

I thought running the view element into the uithread would prevent it from crashing, but for some reason it still crashes(all of this is in a thread). What is the problem with the code? Thanks for any help.

EDIT:

Here is the xml of the activity:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="awsomisoft.yemeb.List"
android:id="@+id/List"
android:background="#ffffffff">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/back_web"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Go"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:background="#ffffffff"
        android:onClick="onBtnClick"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="#ffffffff"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button2" />
</RelativeLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/setscroll"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/URLtextView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/URLtextView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Logcat:

```
07-28 12:03:38.743 341 535 W ActivityManager: Force removing
ActivityRecord{41038b18 awsomisoft.yemeb/.Main}: app died, no saved state
07-28 12:03:38.873 341 614 W InputMethodManagerService: Got
RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 2404 uid 10070
```

Comment: +1 @codeMagic and show us the line where the problem is

Comment: I am only able to use my Nexus for logcat. I am trying to find a logcat app.

Comment: Your IDE will show the output

Comment: My emulator doesn't work. I am testing the app on my Nexus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ScrollView` can have only **one child**.

You cannot add child strait to `ScrollView`, so `linearLayout.addView(tv);` will not work.
Add `LinearLayout` as a child to `ScrollView` and add `TextViews` into `LinearLayout` (or any `GroupView`) instead.

So you need to first modify the XML layout:

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/URLtextView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp">
    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/childsContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:id="@+id/URLtextView"/>
            </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Then instead of adding childs to scrollview (the one with id **linearLayout**) you need to add them to layout( which you need to inflate first) with id **childsContainer**

Comment: How can I do that? It won't allow me to do that.